# Best way to implement Android TabActivity that is not deprecated

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, deprecated

I'm currently re-learning the Android API. I did some projects back then (around Android 2.2 version) and I'm trying to implement a TabActivity that I found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example) but it is already deprecated.

For Android 4.0+ version, what is the best way to implement this? I have read that I can use ViewPager and Fragments but I'm not sure where to start. Any advice? As much as possible, I don't want to use 3<sup>rd</sup> party API's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For Android 4.0+ version, what is the best way to implement this?

Use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) instead of `TabActivity` from `android.support.design.`  to support lower devices also.

> I have read that I can use ViewPager and Fragments but I'm not sure
>   where to start

Use `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` and `Fragment` in `Activity` or `FragmentActvity`.

See following tutorial :

[Android TabLayout Example using ViewPager and Fragments](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)